# working of find(vector.begin(),vector.end(), A[i])==vector.end()

Tags: c++, vector, stl, find

```
if(find(vector.begin(),vector.end(), A[i])==vector.end())
{
    vector.push_back(A[i]);
}
```

I am using it for not entering duplicate elements in the vector.
How actually it is working. If someone can explain it will be really great.

Comment: The key to understanding why that works lies in understanding the return value of [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: It would benefit you to [edit] this question to detail what you understand, and what specifically you don't.  Otherwise, we must guess what you don't understand.  If statements?  Equality comparisons?  `find`?  `push_back`?

Answer (score 1):

[`std::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) takes a range of iterators as input and searches for a given value within that range.  If the value is found, an iterator to that value is returned.  If the value is not found, the specified end iterator is returned.  In this case, since `vector.end()` is the specified end iterator, that is what gets returned if the `A[i]` value is not found in the `vector`.

An easier way to keep a list of values that can't repeat is to use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) or [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead of `std::vector`, eg:

```
#include <set>

std::set<decltype(A)::value_type> s;
...
if (s.insert(A[i]).second) {
    // insert successful, was not a duplicate
}
else {
    // insert failed, was a duplicate
}
...
```